# Deleting row from DataTable?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I have a little probleme with primefaces dataTable,

i have set a commandButton inside my table inorder to delete data from the table

but whene i choose to delete a row i found that it had deleted 2 rows not just one

this is my Bean

```
package com.beans;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import org.primefaces.event.CellEditEvent;
import org.primefaces.event.RowEditEvent;

import com.bo.DiplomeBo;
import com.converter.DiplomeDataModel;
import com.model.Collaborateur;
import com.model.Diplome;

public class DiplomeBean {

    public Integer idDiplome;
    public String ecole;
    public String typeEcole;
    public String typeDiplome;
    public Integer promotion;
    private Set<Collaborateur> collaborateurs = new HashSet<Collaborateur>(0);
    public Diplome selectedDiplome;
    private DiplomeBo diplomeBo;

    public Diplome getSelectedDiplome() {
        return selectedDiplome;
    }

    public void setSelectedDiplome(Diplome selectedDiplome) {
        this.selectedDiplome = selectedDiplome;
    }

    public Integer getIdDiplome() {
        return idDiplome;
    }

    public void setIdDiplome(Integer idDiplome) {
        this.idDiplome = idDiplome;
    }


    public String getEcole() {
        return ecole;
    }

    public void setEcole(String ecole) {
        this.ecole = ecole;
    }

    public String getTypeEcole() {
        return typeEcole;
    }

    public void setTypeEcole(String typeEcole) {
        this.typeEcole = typeEcole;
    }

    public Integer getPromotion() {
        return promotion;
    }

    public void setPromotion(Integer promotion) {
        this.promotion = promotion;
    }

    public Set<Collaborateur> getCollaborateurs() {
        return collaborateurs;
    }

    public void setCollaborateurs(Set<Collaborateur> collaborateurs) {
        this.collaborateurs = collaborateurs;
    }

    public void setDiplomeBo(DiplomeBo diplomeBo) {
        this.diplomeBo = diplomeBo;
    }

    public String getTypeDiplome() {
        return typeDiplome;
    }

    public void setTypeDiplome(String typeDiplome) {
        this.typeDiplome = typeDiplome;
    }

    public String AddDiplome() {
        Diplome diplome = new Diplome();
        diplome.setEcole(getEcole());
        diplome.setPromotion(getPromotion());
        diplome.setTypeDiplome(getTypeDiplome());
        diplome.setTypeEcole(getTypeEcole());
        diplomeBo.addDiplome(diplome);
        clearForm();
        return "Ajout Bien Fait !!";
    }

    public String UpdateDiplome(Diplome dip) {
        diplomeBo.updateDiplome(dip);
        return "Update Bien Fait";
    }

    public String DeleteDiplome(Diplome diplome){
        diplomeBo.deleteDiplome(diplome);
        clearForm();
        return "";
    }

    public List<Diplome> getAllDiplome() {
        return diplomeBo.findAllDiplome();
    }

    private void clearForm() {
        this.setEcole("");
        this.setPromotion(0);
        this.setTypeEcole("");
        this.setTypeEcole("");

    }

    public void onEdit(RowEditEvent event) {
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Diplome Edited");
        Integer i = ((Diplome) (event.getObject())).getIdDiplome();
        Diplome d = new Diplome();
        d.setIdDiplome(i);
        d.setEcole(this.getEcole());
        this.UpdateDiplome(d);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
        clearForm();
    }

    public void onCancel(RowEditEvent event) {
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Diplome Cancelled");

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    }

}
```

this is my page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"  
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"  
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head></h:head> 

<body> 
<f:view>
<h:outputLink value="Admin/default.xhtml">Go to your app</h:outputLink>

        <h:form id="form">

            <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />

            <p:dataTable var="dip" value="#{diplome.getAllDiplome()}" id="diplomeList"
                editable="true">

                <f:facet name="header">  
            In-Cell Editing  
                </f:facet>

                <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{diplome.onEdit}"
                     />
                <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{diplome.onCancel}"
                     />

                <p:column headerText="ID" style="width:10%">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{dip.idDiplome}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputText value="#{dip.idDiplome}#{diplome.idDiplome}" style="width:100%"  readonly="true" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Ecole" style="width:20%">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{dip.ecole}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputText value="#{diplome.ecole}" style="width:100%"  />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>

                <p:column style="width:6%">
                    <p:rowEditor />
                    </p:column>
                 <p:column>
                    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-trash"
                        title="Delete this actor"
                        action="#{diplome.DeleteDiplome(dip)}"
                        ajax="false" />
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>

        </h:form>


    </f:view>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: just debug your delete method to see if it is invoked once or twice, and what is going on inside it.

Comment: Please post the code of your DiplomeBo class (I assume it's a sort of DAO or something). Your managed bean code is quite messy, I'd suggest binding the value of your p:dataTable to an array instance rather than to a method, updating that array in the delete method. The getter method that serves the table value is invoked in more than one phase and accessing a DB from there is wrong.